# Spresense SDKスタートガイド(CLI版)3.1-2 SDKのコンフィギュレーションにてMakefile:38: /tools/Sdk.mk: No such file or directoryになる。

Tags: spresense

Try 'make distclean' first.を実行しても全く同じ現象です、以下はエラーコードです。

```
$ tools/config.py examples/camera
Makefile:38: /tools/Sdk.mk: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target '/tools/Sdk.mk'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [/home/K.Nishikawa/spresense/sdk/apps/Directory.mk:50: camera/_preconfig] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:167: Kconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** [tools/Makefile.unix:601: apps_preconfig] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:220: olddefconfig] Error 2
Post process failed. 512
Try 'make distclean' first.
```

Comment: https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/blob/master/sdk/Makefile#L68
Makefile内で使用している$(SDKDIR)変数が正しく取得できてなさそうです。使用しているプラットフォーム環境(Linux, Mac, Windows)は何でしょうか？初めて環境構築しているのでしょうか？それとも何度かビルドしたことがある環境でしょうか？

Comment: プラットフォームはwindows10です。初めての構築です。Arduinoではうまくいきました。

Comment: <https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_windows向けセットアップ> にある通り、`install-tools.sh` の実行には成功していて、`git clone --recursive https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense.git` リカーシブにcloneもできている状態でしょうか？ コンソールは`MSYS2 MSYS`を使用している状態ですね。`spresense/sdk` ディレクトリ下で `pwd | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g'` コマンドを実行すると正しく動作しているでしょうか？ `tools/config.py -vv examples/camera` のようにverboseオプションを足して実行した結果はどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: 以前と同じエラーのようです。

Comment: K.Nishikawa@DESKTOP-78P4AG7 MSYS ~/spresense/sdk
$ bash install-tools.sh -r
bash: install-tools.sh: No such file or directory
　　install -tools.sh -rを実行するとエラーです、

Comment: マニュアル中の「コンパイラの更新を含めて再インストールを行う場合は、最新の install-tools.sh を取得し -r オプションを付与して install-tools.sh を実行してください。」はなにをすればいいのかわかりません。

Answer (score 0):

環境のセットアップが正しくできていないようです。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_windows向けセットアップ](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_windows%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97)

1. MSYS2をインストール
2. "MSYS2 MSYS" アプリケーションを起動する(MSYS2 MinGW 32/64-bitでは無いです)
3. MSYS2ターミナルからcurlコマンドを実行してinstall-tools.shをダウンロードする

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sonydevworld/spresense/master/install-tools.sh > install-tools.sh
```

4. さきほどダウンロードした`intall-tools.sh`という名前のスクリプトファイルを実行する。開発に必要な各種ツールがインストールされます。

```
bash install-tools.sh
```

5. インストールしたツールを実行可能にするためにパスを通します。

```
source ~/spresenseenv/setup
```

ソニーさんのマニュアルほぼそのままですが、試してみてください。

ちなみに、3,4 について、既に `spresense.git` を `git clone` している状態であれば、`spresense/install-tools.sh` ファイルが存在すると思うので、それを利用することも可能です。

```
cd spresense
bash install-tools.sh
```

Comment: 問題解決御礼、msys2をアンインストールしてもう一度環境設定をやり直しました。有り難うございました。